# Difference between latex compilation on Debian 8 with pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 and MacOS HighSierra

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, citing, biber

I am trying to ge the same output PDF of a report on MacOS Sierra 10.13.6 and Debian 8 (pdfTex 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19) with the following commands :

```
pdflatex rapport_m2
biber rapport_m2
biber rapport_m2
pdflatex rapport_m2
pdflatex rapport_m2
```

My issue is that I can't have references on Debian OS, I get "undefined references" unlikely on MaOS where I get all valid references (I talk about the bibliography).

You can see the log of compilation for both version :

[log compilation on Debian](http://31.207.34.24/code/compilation_debian.log)

[log compilation on MacOS](http://31.207.34.24/code/compilation_macos.log)

The number of pages generated is also different (39 pages on MacOS and only 37 on Debian).

Here is below all the header of my `.tex`report with all options and packages :

```
article{Hamilton_1998,
  author = {{Hamilton}, A.~J.~S.},
  title = {{Linear Redshift Distortions: a Review}},
  booktitle = {The Evolving Universe},
  year = {1998},
  editor = {{Hamilton}, D.},
  volume = {231},
  series = {Astrophysics and Space Science Library},
  pages = {185},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998ASSL..231..185H},
  bdsk-url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-011-4960-0_17},
  doi = {10.1007/978-94-011-4960-0_17},
  eprint = {astro-ph/9708102}
}
\end{filecontents}

%\documentclass[11pt,french,oneside]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\documentclass[11pt,french,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{psboxit,pstcol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\Crefname{appendix}{l'Appendice}{les Appendices}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{caption}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}

% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{9} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{9}  % for normal

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttm,
otherkeywords={self},             % Add keywords here
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
showstringspaces=false,
%commentstyle=\fontseries{lc}\selectfont\itshape,columns=fullflexible], 
commentstyle=\ttb\selectfont\itshape,columns=fullflexible], 
numbers=left,
stepnumber=1,
}}


% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
{
\pythonstyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}

% Python for external files
\newcommand\pythonexternal[2][]{{
\pythonstyle
\lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newcommand*{\x}{\mathsf{x}\mskip1mu}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand{\emptysection}[1]{%
    \begingroup\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}%
    \section{#1}\endgroup%
}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\chapter@number@width}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  {\normalfont
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \vspace*{10pt}%
  \settowidth{\chapter@number@width}{%
    \hbox{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries
          \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
          \thechapter
          \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
    }}
  \hbox{%
    \vtop{%
      \hsize=\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+\tabcolsep+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c}
        \scshape\strut\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}\@chapapp\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}} \\
        \fboxsep=0pt
        \colorbox{black}{\vbox{%
           \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+3pt{}}
           \hbox{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                 \thechapter
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                }
           \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 0pt
           \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
           \hbox{\parbox{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\vphantom{E}}}
           }}%
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    \vtop{%
      \advance\hsize by -\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
      \hspace*{-0.5cm}\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \scshape\strut\vphantom{\@chapapp} \\
        \fboxsep=0pt
        \colorbox{white}{\vbox{%
           \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+3pt{}}
           \hbox{\LARGE\bfseries
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                 \phantom{\thechapter}
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                }
           \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \hsize
           \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
           \hbox{\hspace*{20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2mm-6pt-\chapter@number@width-\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule-20pt}{\Huge\bfseries #1}}
           }}%
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }%
  \vspace{50pt}%
  }
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  {\normalfont
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \vspace*{10pt}%
  \settowidth{\chapter@number@width}{%
    \hbox{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries
          \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
          \thechapter
          \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
    }}
  \hbox{%
    \vtop{%
      \hsize=\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+\tabcolsep+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c}
        \scshape\strut\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}\phantom{\@chapapp}\hspace{0pt plus 1 fill minus 1 fill}} \\
        \fboxsep=0pt
        \colorbox{black}{\vbox{%
           \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+3pt{}}
           \hbox{\color{white}\LARGE\bfseries
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                 \phantom{\thechapter}%
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                }
           \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width 0pt
           \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
           \hbox{\parbox{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries\vphantom{E}}}
           }}%
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    \vtop{%
      \advance\hsize by -\dimexpr\chapter@number@width+2\fboxrule+\tabcolsep
      \hspace*{-0.5cm}\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \scshape\strut\vphantom{\@chapapp} \\
        \fboxsep=0pt
        \colorbox{white}{\vbox{%
           \hbox{\vbox to \dimexpr 1mm+3pt{}}
           \hbox{\LARGE\bfseries
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                 \phantom{\thechapter}
                 \hspace{\dimexpr 1mm+3pt}%
                }
           \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \hsize
           \hbox{\vbox to 6pt{}}
           \hbox{\hspace*{20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2mm-6pt-\chapter@number@width-\tabcolsep-2\fboxrule-20pt}{\Huge\bfseries #1}}
           }}%
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }%
  \vspace{50pt}%
  }
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

%%%% debut macro pour changer les marges localement %%%%
\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt plus 1pt}%
\addtolength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\addtolength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
}\item }{\end{list}}
%%%% fin macro %%%%

%\setmarginsrb{2.3cm}{0.3cm}{2.1cm}{1cm}{0.55cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\setmarginsrb{2.3cm}{0.0cm}{2.1cm}{1cm}{1.3cm}{0.5cm}{0.4cm}{1cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\chead{\hspace{-0.3cm}\textit{Rapport \hspace{-0.3cm}}}
\lhead{\epsfig{file=logo_sdc_small.jpg,height=1cm,width=2cm}}
\rhead{\epsfig{file=logo_par3_small.png,height=1cm,width=2cm}}
\lfoot{\textit{christian joe}}
\cfoot{\hspace{1.6cm} \textit{ - \'etude des mat\'eriaux - }} 
\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \hypertarget{appendixstart}{}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\hyperlink{appendixstart}{Appendice}}{}{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25} 

\begin{document}
```

I apply references by writting : `\autocite{2009MNRAS.399.2107K}`

Unfortunately, on Debian OS, I can't get to have the references displayed correctly, I have just the `name` appearing in `\autocite{name}`.

From all these, informations anyone could tell me where the problem comes from, I mean why this difference between the ouput of the 2 OS ?

**UPDATE 1:** Indeed, this a problem with `biber`and this following message :

```
Output written on rapport_m2.pdf (37 pages, 1289330 bytes).
Transcript written on rapport_m2.log.
INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'rapport_m2.blg'
INFO - Reading 'rapport_m2.bcf'
INFO - Found 23 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'rapport_m2.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash: Inappropriate ioctl for device
./compil_rapport: line 14: 24506 Segmentation fault      biber rapport_m2
```

It seems coming from an issue from comma into my references "@article" : But why don't I have problems on MacOS and this issue on Debian/Linux, it's weird ...

**UPDATE 2:** I have more informations about my issue by doing :

```
$ biber --tool --debug debug_bib.tex
INFO - This is Biber 2.12 running in TOOL mode
INFO - Logfile is 'debug_bib.tex.blg'
INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'debug_bib.tex.blg'
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'debug_bib.tex'
Use of uninitialized value $benc in string eq at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1465.
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 11, warning: 63 characters of junk seen at toplevel
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 418, warning: 2105 characters of junk seen at toplevel
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 418, warning: "}" in strange place -- should get a syntax error
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 418, syntax error: found "}", expected one of: start of entry ("{" or "(") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
invalid token near line 419 (text was '\')
invalid token near line 419 (text was '\')
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 470, warning: 5 characters of junk seen at toplevel
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1516.
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 470, syntax error: found "#", expected one of: start of entry ("{" or "(") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 550, warning: 907 characters of junk seen at toplevel
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1516.
invalid token near line 550 (text was '\')
/tmp/Dh8o_Onbpd/debug_bib.tex_27990.utf8, line 550, syntax error: found "ppendix", expected one of: start of entry ("{" or "(") or quoted string ({...} or "...")
invalid token near line 551 (text was '\')
invalid token near line 552 (text was '\')
invalid token near line 553 (text was '\')
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1516.
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "feb"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "may"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "nov"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "mar"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "oct"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "aug"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jul"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "apr"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jun"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jan"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "dec"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "sep"
FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

my file debug_bib.tex is located on this link : [latex source for debuggging biber](http://31.207.34.24/code/debug_bib.tex)

**UPDATE 3:**

Here is the output of biber of MacOS version (where it compiles fine) :

```
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "mar"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jul"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "feb"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "sep"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "nov"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "may"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "oct"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jun"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "aug"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "apr"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "jan"
warning: overriding existing definition of macro "dec"
warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
author, warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
Use of uninitialized value $end in substitution (s///) at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.28/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1023.
Use of uninitialized value $end in substitution (s///) at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.28/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1023.
INFO - This is Biber 2.11
INFO - Logfile is 'rapport_m2.blg'
INFO - DEBUG mode: all messages are logged to 'rapport_m2.blg'
INFO - Reading 'rapport_m2.bcf'
INFO - Found 23 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'rapport_m2.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ... 
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'rapport_m2.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'fr-FR' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'fr-FR' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nyt' and locale 'fr-FR'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'fr-FR'
INFO - Writing 'rapport_m2.bbl' with encoding 'latin1'
INFO - Output to rapport_m2.bbl
```

with the `.blg` file asscoiated :

[MacOS blg file output biber](http://31.207.34.24/code/blg_log_biber_MacOS.txt)

and the `.blg` of Debian :

[Debian blg file output biber](http://31.207.34.24/code/Debian_blg_file_biber.txt)

It would be interesting to compare them but it is difficult.

Comment: biber is not working on debian, you get perl errors: `Can't locate autovivification.pm in @INC (you may need to install the autovivification module)`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have installed libautovivification-perl_0.18-1+b1_amd64.deb package which provides `autovivification` module and `autovivification.pm` file but issue remains. What is the alternative to biber on Debian/Linux ?

Comment: you need biber with biblatex. I'm on windows and can't help you to debug a debian problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer However, I have declared as you can see above : `\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}`, does it come from this ?

Comment: put `\listfiles` as first line into your document and compare the two file lists which itself can be found at the end of the log files.

Comment: @Red-Cloud the main problem is not a version problem. In the middle of the posted log-file is the output of biber which shows that biber fails due to a perl error.

Comment: Ah, didn't noticed it. I'll install Debian 8, to see what happens.

Comment: Isn't Deian 8, like, very, very old?

Comment: Running Biber twice in a row without any other command in between is superfluous. Unlike LaTeX, Biber does not consume the auxiliary files it writes itself. Biber just produces the `.bbl` (to be read by LaTeX) based on the `.bcf` (written by LaTeX) and the static `.bib` file. The result will always be the same if the `.bcf` and `.bib` are the same. Since those files don't change during a Biber run, running Biber twice without anything in between is of no use whatsoever and will give the exact same result in all possible cases as a single Biber run.

Comment: there is an interesting discussion on https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/599 but I didn't understand the solution suggested on this link, Maybe this is not the same kind of issue, however it looks like

Comment: Debian's Biber is not the 'compiled'/packed version it is the raw Perl version. This would explain why you had to install missing modules. That can't really explain why you get errors that you don't get on the other machine, though (if I'm clutching at straws I might suggest that some of the loaded Perl modules have different versions than expected). In any case you should resolve all errors in your `.bib` file. `author = {LSST Dark Energy Science Collaboration and al.},` is completely wrong and `author = {{LSST Dark Energy Science Collaboration} and al.},` should have `other` and not `al.`

Comment: `author = {{Albrecht}, A., and al.},` has a suprefluous comma that can really trip up `btpase`. `author = {Albrecht, A. and others},` would be correct. `author  = {Lewis PA., Challinor A., Lasenby A.},` is similarly wrong, it should be `author  = {Lewis, PA. and Challinor, A. and Lasenby, A.},`.  `author  = {{Euclid Collaboration} and al.},` is also wrong, see `LSST` above. Some of these *must* have produced a message also on your Mac.

Comment: The call `biber --tool --debug debug_bib.tex` is not helpful to debug the problem since it runs Biber in tool mode on the `.tex` file. You need to call `biber --debug debug_bib` after you have run `pdflatex debug_bib` (on the `.tex` file) [this is assuming the `.tex` file is called `debug_bib.tex`].

Comment: @moewe But what I don't understand, that's on MacOS, compilation is fine with good references which are well displayed whereas on Debian, the references are not taken into acount : have you got an explanation ?

Comment: As I say, I can't really explain that. But you definitely have errors in your file that must be fixed. Can you upload the `.blg` of `biber --debug debug_bib` instead of `biber --tool --debug debug_bib.tex`, please?

Comment: here are the 2 files with and without `--tool` option : http://31.207.34.24/code/log_debug_tool_bib.txt and http://31.207.34.24/code/log_debug_bib.txt and the `.blg` from Debian : http://31.207.34.24/code/debug_bib_DEBIAN.blg

Comment: OK that `.blg` looks more like I expected. The error message could well be caused by the incorrect names I mentioned above (in particular by those names with too many commas). On my machine I observed a while ago that Biber would only occasionally crash on a bad entry, maybe it is a similarly elusive issue here: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/87

Comment: @moewe we could say that biber on MacOS is more tolerant than on Debian

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be. In any case it should at least issue a warning. Do things work if you fix your `.bib` file as mentioned in the comments above?

Comment: The Mac OS log also mentions a series of issues: `warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
author, warning: comma(s) at end of name (removing)
Use of uninitialized value $end in substitution (s///) at /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.28/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm line 1023`

Comment: I also notice that the Biber on Mac identifies as 2.11 while the Debian log says version 2.12. That might explain the differences.